# DB Migration with helm

Tags: kubernetes, hook, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to migrate our cassandra tables to use `liquibase`. Basically the idea is trivial, have a `pre-install` and `pre-upgrade` job that will run some `liquibase` scripts and will manage our database upgrade.

For that purpose I have created a custom docker image that will have the actual `liquibase cli` and then I can invoke it from the job. For example:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: "{{ .Release.Name }}-update-job"
  namespace: spring-k8s
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ .Release.Service | quote }}
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name | quote }}
    app.kubernetes.io/version: {{ .Chart.AppVersion }}
    helm.sh/chart: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version }}"
  annotations:
    # This is what defines this resource as a hook. Without this line, the
    # job is considered part of the release.
    "helm.sh/hook": pre-install, pre-upgrade
    "helm.sh/hook-weight": "5"
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": before-hook-creation
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: "{{ .Release.Name }}-cassandra-update-job"
      namespace: spring-k8s
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ .Release.Service | quote }}
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name | quote }}
        helm.sh/chart: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version }}"
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Never
      containers:
        - name: pre-install-upgrade-job
          image: "lq/liquibase-cassandra:1.0.0"
          command: ["/bin/bash"]
          args:
            - "-c"
            - "./liquibase-cassandra.sh --username {{ .Values.liquibase.username }} --password {{ .Values.liquibase.username }} --url {{ .Values.liquibase.url | squote }} --file {{ .Values.liquibase.file }}"
```

Where `.Values.liquibase.file` == `databaseChangelog.json`.

So this image `lq/liquibase-cassandra:1.0.0` basically has a script `liquibase-cassandra.sh` that when passed some arguments can do its magic and update the DB schema (not going to go into the details).

The problem is that last argument: `--file {{ .Values.liquibase.file }}`. This file resides *not* in the image, obviously, but in each micro-services repository.

I need a way to "copy" that file to the image, so that I could invoke it. One way would be to build this `lq/liquibase-cassandra` all the time (with the same lifecycle of the project itself) and copy the file into it, but that will take time and seems like at least cumbersome. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that `helm` hooks can be used for other things, not only jobs. As such, I can mount this file into a `ConfigMap` *before* the Job even starts (the file I care about resides in `resources/databaseChangelog.json`):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: "liquibase-changelog-config-map"
  namespace: spring-k8s
  annotations:
    helm.sh/hook: pre-install, pre-upgrade
    helm.sh/hook-delete-policy: hook-succeeded
    helm.sh/hook-weight: "1"
data:
{{ (.Files.Glob "resources/*").AsConfig | indent 2 }}
```

And then just reference it inside the job:

```
  .....
  spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  volumes:
    - name: liquibase-changelog-config-map
      configMap:
        name: liquibase-changelog-config-map
        defaultMode: 0755
  containers:
    - name: pre-install-upgrade-job
      volumeMounts:
        - name: liquibase-changelog-config-map
          mountPath: /liquibase-changelog-file
      image: "lq/liquibase-cassandra:1.0.0"
      command: ["/bin/bash"]
      args:
        - "-c"
        - "./liquibase-cassandra.sh --username {{ .Values.liquibase.username }} --password {{ .Values.liquibase.username }} --url {{ .Values.liquibase.url | squote }} --file {{ printf "/liquibase-changelog-file/%s" .Values.liquibase.file }}"
```